# Gaming: Ravensword libxcursor1 error

Tags: xubuntu, 14.04, games

Xubuntu 14.04, 64 bit, I paid for a  humble bundle package and got Ravensword, downloaded the Linux edition when I run `./rs2.x86` I get

> ./rs2.x86 ./rs2.x86: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libXcursor.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

I run

```
▶ sudo apt-get install libxcursor1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libxcursor1 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

so

```
locate libxcursor1 
/usr/share/doc/libxcursor1
/usr/share/doc/libxcursor1/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libxcursor1/copyright
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libxcursor1:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libxcursor1:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libxcursor1:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libxcursor1:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libxcursor1:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libxcursor1:i386.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libxcursor1:i386.postrm
```

I tried reinstalling that library, I tried installing all of these

[image]

nothing worked.

**UPDATE**

after `sudo apt-get install libxcursor1:i386`

I get

```
▶ ./rs2.x86                                                     
Set current directory to /home/elie/Games/Ravensword_linux
Found path: /home/elie/Games/Ravensword_linux/rs2.x86
Mono path[0] = '/home/elie/Games/Ravensword_linux/rs2_Data/Managed'
Mono path[1] = '/home/elie/Games/Ravensword_linux/rs2_Data/Mono'
Mono config path = '/home/elie/Games/Ravensword_linux/rs2_Data/Mono/etc'
Creating user config folder: /home/elie/.config/unity3d
PlayerPrefs - Creating folder: /home/elie/.config/unity3d/Crescent Moon Games LLC
PlayerPrefs - Creating folder: /home/elie/.config/unity3d/Crescent Moon Games LLC/Ravensword2
[1]    14591 abort (core dumped)  ./rs2.x86
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libxcursor1:i386
```

(this will install 32-bit library)

Comment: I updated my question, I think we're getting somewhere now

Comment: It looks like you have newer libraries, than this game was compiled for. All you can do is send them an e-mail, here http://support.humblebundle.com/

Comment: i did so just after asking the question, lets hope they reply, I also gave them a link to this question so they can read it and see what's wrong